# angularjs XXXService.XXXfunction is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is my first try writing up a service in AngularJS. I have a service, in which I have a function. When I call this service from my controller, it says XXXService.XXXfunction is not a function.

My Javascript is like,

```
var sharecycle0_angularfire = angular.module("sharecycle0_angularfire", []);

sharecycle0_angularfire.service("baseHttp", function($http, $q){


  self.getFire = function(){

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http({
        method: GET,
        url: "https://boiling-inferno-1234.firebaseio.com/Cat"
      }).then(function(response){
        deferred.resolve(response);
      },function(response){
        deferred.reject(resposne);
  });

  return deferred.promise;

  };

});

sharecycle0_angularfire.controller("angularfirecontroller", function($scope, baseHttp, $window){

  $scope.fireClick = function(){

      baseHttp.getFire()
      .then(
          function(response)
          {
              $("<div/>").text(response).appendTo($("#successData"));
          },
          function(response)
          {
              $window.alert("error: "+response);
          }
      );

  };

});
```

My HTML is like,

```
<body ng-controller="angularfirecontroller">
    <button id="fireClickButton" ng-click="fireClick()">fireClick</button>
    <div id="successData"/>
</body>
```

I expect the service code to run upon my button being hit.

Comment: You never return `getFire`, so your `baseHttp.getFire()` will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues here, you are not attaching the function `getFire` to the service instance, instead you are attaching it to the global variable **`self`**. `self` global variable is generally an alias to window object in many browsers so you are attaching the function to the window and not to the controller instance. Since `http` already returns a promise you do not need to create a deferred object there, instead just return the result of `$http`. Apart from that `GET` needs to be a string value, you are trying to use an undefined variable `GET` and not `"GET"`. Many a times placing a debug log in relevant areas of the code will help you diagnose the issue.

All you would need is:

```
sharecycle0_angularfire.service("baseHttp", function($http, $q){
  this.getFire = function(){
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "https://boiling-inferno-1234.firebaseio.com/Cat"
      });
    }
});
```

if you intended to cache `this` then you should create a local variable and assign `this` to that.

i.e

```
sharecycle0_angularfire.service("baseHttp", function($http, $q){
  var _this = this; //Or var self = this
  _this.getFire = function(){
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "https://boiling-inferno-1234.firebaseio.com/Cat"
      });
    }
});
```